# Doctrine ManyToMany cleanup

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

My Project entity has a ManyToMany relation with my User entity.
This creates a join table as expected.

If i delete a project entity i would like all rows in the join table with the project entity's id to get deleted as well, but this does not happen.

How would i achieve this kind of behaviour?
I already tried `orphanremoval=true`

Here is the relevant part of my project entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProjectRepository::class)
 */
class Project
{
    ...
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class)
     */
    private $userProjectManagers;

    ...
}
```

Same should happen if i delete a user. I guess i have to add a field in my User Entity with mappedBy / inversedBy.

Although i'm not sure if that is bad practice, as i dont need that field except for the join table row deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working like this:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProjectRepository::class)
 */
class Project
{
    ...
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="pmProjects")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="project_user",
     *     joinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     }
     * )
     */
    private $userProjectManagers;

    ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Project::class, mappedBy="userProjectManagers")
     */
    private $pmProjects;
    ...

}
```